# select only one of multiple class in a single html element using querySelector in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

For example

let's say there are bunch of div elements with two class names in each like this.

```html
<div class="color red"></div>
<div class="color aqua"></div>
<div class="color green"></div>
<div class="color blue"></div>
<div class="color yellow"></div>
```

In CSS that would be:

```css
.color{
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}
.red{background: red;}
.aqua{background: aqua;}
.green{background: green;}
.blue{background: blue;}
.yellow{background: yellow;}
```

Now I want to add "click" event listener to each div element targeting it's "color" class name such that when I click it, it should alert the second class name i.e. the name of the color. All of this in plain javascript. How do I do that? My approach was

```
let $$ = document.querySelectorAll.bind(document);

$$(".color").forEach(clickedBox)

function clickedBox(value){
  value.addEventListener("click", some_function);
}

function some_function(){
  ......................
  ......................
  alert(..............);
}
```

I got stuck here. What sould be the content of some_function() so that whenever I click the box, it will alert me the second class name of each respective div element?

Answer (score 0):

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.color').forEach(item => {
  item.addEventListener('click', event => {
    console.log(item.classList[1])
  })
})
```

```html
<div class="color red">red</div>
<div class="color aqua">aqua</div>
<div class="color green">green</div>
<div class="color blue">blue</div>
<div class="color yellow">yellow</div>
```

Comment: Thank You Very Much. I just didn't know about classList. I only knew about className which would display both the class names and used slice method.

Comment: @JePayeTyai Glad it helped, please consider marking this answer as accepted with ✔︎ so it marks this question as solved for others. Cheers